# Where can I download Oracle JDK/JRE 5 update 32 (or latest)?

Tags: java

According to [Oracle Java SE Critical Patch Update Advisory - October 2011](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/javacpuoct2011-443431.html)
the fixes affect "JDK and JRE 5.0 Update 31 and earlier" among other Java SE releases.

Where can I download the latest Java 5.0 update that I assume is 32?

The [Java SE Downloads - Previous Release - J2SE 5.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jdk5-jsp-142662.html) page still shows Java 5.0 update 22 as the latest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 5 has long met its End-of-Life and is no longer supported by Oracle (since November 2009, according to [this Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0_.28September_30.2C_2004.29)).

Newer updates are *only* available through the [Java for Business](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/overview/index.html) program, which effectively requires a paid support contract.

If you want the latest security fixes and don't want to pay for them, then you need to update to *at least* Java 6.

Answer (score 1):

J2SE 5.0 End of Service Life Notice
J2SE 5.0 reached its End of Service Life (EOSL) on November 3, 2009, which is the date of the final publicly available update of version 5.0 (J2SE 5.0 Update 22). Migrate to Java 6